# Forms border in Angular

Tags: angular

I am build a small angular project. I have the following situation

```
<mat-toolbar class="toolbar" color="primary">
  <span>
    E-commerce
  </span>
  <mat-form-field class="researchForm">
      <input matNativeControl>
  </mat-form-field>

</mat-toolbar>
```

with the following css-style

```
.toolbar {
  background:#303030;
  color: #ffffff;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.researchForm{
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-size-adjust: auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 95%;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%!important;

}
```

with the following result
[image]

The problem is that i want to se the bottom borders of my form but as we can see the form is not perfectly in the center of the toolbar. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hey there! I'm not sure what might help in your case but I be glad to help. If you could provide a stackblitz or similiar, I maybe could tell you whats going on.

Comment: The problem is that i can't show the bottom border of the form

Comment: mat-form-field is extended into several div's. So you can't apply border-radius using `.researchForm`. Inspect your mat-from-field in devTools and look which of div has border-top-radus left and right. Then apply border-bottom-radius left and right to this div.